# Getting row number when day changes on column 1 with dates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to get the row number of the first row of a block of dates of the same day using GAS?

[image]

In this case I needed to get the row number "38" since its the first row of the block of rows for the 5th of September.

At the moment I am using:

```
function groupDays() {
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('LOG');
rowStart = sheet.getLastRow() - 24;
rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
  groupDates(dates, 'date');
}
```

I did not post the whole script because it's a bit long. I'm using the script to group rows by day, month and year. Right now I am trying to work on **the group rows by day** part.
So the `rowStart`variable is the row number from where the script will start grouping rows. This `rowStart` variable needs to advance as the rows keep getting recorded otherwise whenever the script is executed groups will be duplicated, triplicated, quadruplicated etc.

Problem is I think `-24`is not a good way to do this because sometimes data won't get recorded because of a Google Trigger error so a couple of rows might get skipped which will cause the grouping function to start at a row that is already grouped to the previous day which will duplicate the group for that previous day.

The script will be executed when comparing the 2 last rows it detects the last row advanced a day. Then it is supposed to create a group for the rows belonging to the day that just ended and which are ungrouped.

So again is there a way to use Google Apps Script to get the row number for the first row of a block of rows for the last day?

Here is my dummy file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT:

I used one of the answers bellow with some changes:

```
function getRowDay() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LOG");
  var dateDay = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValue();
  var dayPlusMonth = Utilities.formatDate(dateDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YYYY");
  var cells = sheet.getRange("A5:A").createTextFinder(dayPlusMonth).findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
  var firstRowOfDay = cells[0];
  //return cells[0];
  // log start
  console.log(dayPlusMonth);
  console.log(firstRowOfDay);
  console.log(sheet);
  console.log(dateDay);
  console.log(cells);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can extract the latest date by using `.getLastRow()` and then use the cell's value as a text finder parameter to find all cells that start with the date.*

#### Code:

```
function getRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOG")
  const date = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getDisplayValue().slice(0, 11)

  const cells = sheet.getRange("A1:A").createTextFinder(date).findAll().map(x => x.getRow())

  return cells[0]

}
```

**Rundown of this code:**

- Gets the sheet named `LOG`.
- Gets the last cell in column A of this sheet, and extracts the first 10 characters of the cell (this will be the date portion without the time, e.g `06/09/2021`)
- Uses a text finder to search column A for all cells that contain this date
- Maps these cell ranges to their corresponding row number
- Returns the first cell in column A that starts with this date

#### References:

- [Class Sheet / `createTextFinder(findText)` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way to go. Just use the below `findIndex()` function and give it the day, month and year to look for and the data from the spreadsheet. Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```js
const findIndex = (day, month, year, rows) =>
  rows.findIndex(
    row =>
      new Date(row[0]).getDate() === day &&
      new Date(row[0]).getMonth() === month - 1 &&
      new Date(row[0]).getFullYear() === year
  ) + 1;

const yourFunc = () => {
  const rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  const index = findIndex(5, 9, 2021, rows); // first row for 5th of September
  console.log(index);
};
```

Comment: I used something else for this you can check it on my main text. I couldn't get this one to work because I couldn't understand how it work and therefore couldn't connect it to my script. Is there something I should know about to get this one to work? Is there any advantage to use this one instead of the one I found to work? Thanks!

Comment: @Verminous you shall no use it. It's a piece of pure art of functional style coding! :)

Comment: @Verminous you just copy paste `findIndex()` as a separate function in your script and use it the way it's used in the `yourFunc()` that serves as an example. If you are confused by the syntax, look into arrow functions in JavaScript.