# How to `setNumberFormat()`date format for Hong Kong and other similar countries with special characters in the date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, format, spreadsheet

So I'm running some code that will group rows and change the date format of an entire column and set the date and time format according to the Locale chosen by the user on the Spreadsheet settings. Something like this:

```
// Identify Sheet.
var logSheetNameYR = "LOG";
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetNameYR);
// Get "Locale" from Spreadsheet Settings.
var locale = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetLocale();
// 1st part of tweak to get the number of first row of block of rows of previous day + tweak for date format US/EU etc.
var rowBlock = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();
// Conditional variable for date formats defined according to locale on spreadsheet settings. Also forces date format on column A.
var getDayMonthYear;
switch (locale) {
    case 'en_US':
    case 'en_CA':
    case 'en_ZA':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('m"/"d"/"yyyy" "h":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/YYYY");
        break;
    case 'sv_SE':
    case 'pl_PL':
    case 'fr_CA':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy"-"mm"-"dd" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY-MM-dd");
        break;
    case 'lt_LT':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy"-"mm"-"dd" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY-MM-dd");
        break;
    case 'hu_HU':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy"."mm"."dd". "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY.MM.dd");
        break;
    case 'zh_CN':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy"-"m"-"d" "am/pm""hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY-M-d");
        break;
    case 'pt_PT':
    case 'ja_JP':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy"/"mm"/"dd" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY/MM/dd");
        break;
    case 'es_ES':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('d"/"mm"/"yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d/MM/YYYY");
        break;
    case 'de_CH':
    case 'no_NO':
    case 'nn_NO':
    case 'bg_BG':
    case 'uk_UA':
    case 'be_BY':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('dd"."mm"."yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd.MM.YYYY");
        break;
    case 'nl_NL':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('d"-"m"-"yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d-M-YYYY");
        break;
    case 'hr_HR':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('d"."m"."yyyy". "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d.M.YYYY");
        break;
    case 'fi_FI':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('d"."m"."yyyy" "hh"."mm"."ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d.M.YYYY");
        break;
    case 'cs_CZ':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('d"."m"."yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d.M.YYYY");
        break;
    case 'ka_GE':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('dd"."mm"."yy", "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd.MM.YY");
        break;
    case 'el_GR':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('dd"/"mm"/"yyyy" "h":"mm":"ss"."am/pm');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YYYY");
        break;
    case 'ko_KR':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy". "m". "d" "am/pm" "h":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY. M. d");
        break;
    case 'sl_SI':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('d". "m". "yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d. M. YYYY");
        break;
    case 'sk_SK':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('d"."m"."yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d.M.YYYY");
        break;
    case 'zh_HK':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy"年"m"月"d"日 "am/pm""hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY年M月d日");
        break;
    case 'th_TH':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('d"/"m"/"yyyy", "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d/M/YYYY");
        break;
    case 'es_VE':
    case 'es_UY':
    case 'es_MX':
    case 'es_CL':
    case 'es_CO':
    case 'es_EC':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('d"/"m"/"yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d/M/YYYY");
        break;
    case 'zh_TW':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy"/"m"/"d" "a/p""午" "h":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY/M/d");
        break;
    case 'lv_LV':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy"."d"."m" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY.d.M");
        break;
    case 'ar_EG':
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('h":"m":"ss" "a/p" "yyyy"/"mm"/"dd');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY/MM/dd");
        break;
    default:
        sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('dd"/"mm"/"yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss');
        getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YYYY");
        console.log("no locale detected");
}
// 2nd part of tweak for getting the number of first row of block of rows of previous day.
var cells = sheet.getRange("A5:A").createTextFinder(getDayMonthYear).findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
var firstRowOfBlock = cells[0];
var rowStart = firstRowOfBlock;

// Group rows by years.
function group_by_years2() {
    // Grouping Function.
    get_rows_array().forEach(y => shift_rows2(y.map(m => m.flat()).flat(), sheet));
    // Collapse group.
    let groupClps = sheet.getRowGroup(firstRowOfBlock, 1);
    groupClps.collapse();
}

// Group rows by months.
function group_by_months2() {
    // Grouping function.
    get_rows_array().flat().forEach(m => shift_rows2(m.flat(), sheet));
    // Collapse group.
    let groupClps = sheet.getRowGroup(firstRowOfBlock, 1);
    groupClps.collapse();
}

// group rows by days
function group_by_days2() {
    // Grouping Function
    get_rows_array2().flat().flat().forEach(d => shift_rows2(d.flat(), sheet))
    // Collapse group
    let groupClps = sheet.getRowGroup(firstRowOfBlock, 1);
    groupClps.collapse();
}

function get_rows_array2() {
    var timeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetNameYR);
    var rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
    var values = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
    var o = {};

    // make the object {'year': { 'month':[days] } }
    values.forEach((date, i) => {
        var [y, m, d] = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, "MM,dd,yyyy").split(",");
        // console.log(y, m, d);
        if (!o[y]) o[y] = {};
        if (!o[y][m]) o[y][m] = {};
        if (!o[y][m][d]) o[y][m][d] = [];
        o[y][m][d].push(rowStart + i);
    });

    // convert the unordered object {year:{month:[days]}}
    // into the ordered 3d-array [year[month[days]]]
    const numsort = (a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
    return Object.keys(o).sort(numsort)
        .map(y => Object.keys(o[y]).sort(numsort)
            .map(m => Object.values(o[y][m]).sort(numsort)));
}

function shift_rows2(rows, sheet) {
    if (rows.length === 1) return;
    var range = `${rows[1]}:${rows.slice(-1)}`;
    sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
}
```

Problem is when some countries are chosen like Hong Kong and a few others which will include in the date format special characters, I can't figure out how to use `setNumberFormat()` to emulate/imitate the same date format with those special characters or foreign alphabet characters etc.

I was trying out with Hong Kong by choosing in the Spreadsheet Settings the Locale as Hong Kong and the result I get when recording a new row with present date is this:

[image]

Now the rows above this one are using different date/time format depending on the previous locale chosen. I want the entire column to look exactly like the last one.
Best option I could find was:

```
('dd"/"mm"/"yyyy" "h":"mm":"ss"."a/p')
```

The `a/p` part will had 1 special character similar to the ones used by the sheet but that's it.

Dummy file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT:

I can also try do decipher / translate the characters and add them manually to the code then use `a/p` when necessary like this:

```
  case 'zh_HK':
  sheet.getRange("A:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy"年"m"月"d"日"a/p""午""hh":"mm":"ss'); 
  getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(dateDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY年M月d日");
```

Maybe there is a better, faster and automated way to do this?
I also tried to get the format with `getNumberFormat()`hoping the console would give me format then just copy paste it but with default formats that are changed with the Locale option return blank.

EDIT2:

So for Hong Kong and a few others like Greece etc `am/pm` helps:

```
yyyy"年"m"月"d"日 "am/pm""hh":"mm":"ss
```

Comment: Just a comment: Are you familiar with the JavaScript [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object for handling internationalization? In your case, take a look at [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

Comment: So, for example, you can control formatting like this:  My test date: `const testDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 11, 20, 3, 23, 16, 738));`. The same date in Hong Kong long style: `console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('zh-HK', { dateStyle: 'full', timeStyle: 'long' }).format(testDate));`. The output is: `2020年12月19日星期六 下午10:23:16 [EST]`. There are many flexible formatting options. Note the hyphen in the language tag: `zh-HK` not `zh_HK`.

Comment: That's good. I'd like to use that to format an entire column the same way, and also to retrieve the `dd/MM/YYYY`order info to then use `createTextFinder` like above. But it's not working. If I could do that that would save space and I would not need all those lines of code using the `switch`statement. `getNumberFormat()` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have the vague feeling that all this approach is a dead end. If you need just grab the part of contents of the cell from the last row and find where this part occurs first time in the table, I believe it can be done without converting the contents into dates. You could consider them as just plain strings. *Strings* could be compared no matter what the language or formatting they have. Probably you could `getDisplayValue()` of the cell from last row, split it by space and find for first part of it with TextFinder. No matter if there are hieroglyphs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the working code for filtering rows with dates with any date format and locale and then grouping those rows:

```
// Used for getting the arrays with blocks of rows of `d`+ `m`+ `y`
let range = sheet.getRange("A5:A");
let startRow = range.getRow();
let [y, m, d] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "yyyy,MM,dd").split(",");


  let cells = range.getValues().map((x, i) => x.concat(i + startRow)).filter(x => {   // filter "dd"
        let date = new Date(x[0]);
        let day = date.getDate();
        let month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        return (`${d}` === `${day}` && `${m}` === `${month}` && `${y}` === `${year}`)
    }).map(x => x[1]);
```

When I wan't to group by month, the `return` will be:

```
return (`${m}` === `${month}` && `${y}` === `${year}`)
```

And by group by year:

```
return (`${y}` === `${year}`)
```

This well give me the row numbers into an array, then I get the `0` position with `cells[0]` to find the row number where the group handle will be placed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Since nobody answers, I'd propose to put these murk Date objects and TextFider tricks away. As far as I can see all you need is just to find the number of the first row that contains the same day (not the same time) as the last row in your table.

Thus you don't even need to know the format of these dates. You can consider them as text strings. Left-hand side or every string is a date (whatever format it has), right-hand side is a time. You can just grab these left-hand halves and compare them.

Here is the function that return the number of the row:

```
function main() {
  var the_row = get_row_num();
  console.log(the_row);
}


function get_row_num() {
  var sheet     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var first_row = 5;
  var last_row  = sheet.getLastRow() - first_row + 1;

  const date_without_time = date => date.replace(/\s/,'|').split('|')[0]; // 'date time' --> 'date'

  var range     = sheet.getRange(first_row,1,last_row,1);
  var days      = range.getDisplayValues().flat().map(x => date_without_time(x));
  var last_day  = days[days.length-1];
 
  for (var num in days.reverse()) 
    if (days[num] != last_day) return last_row - +num + first_row;

  return sheet.getLast(row);
}
```

Pure JS. Just a loop trough just an array.

Not exactly a direct answer. A solution, rather.

**Update**

Here is another pure JS example (you can run it with the button) how you can find for "first" (last from the bottom) row for given year, month or day in given list of dates.

```js
// array of dates just for this JS demo. 
// In SpreadsheetApp you will get the dates (objects!) directly via 'range.getValues()'
var dates_str = [
    '2020/08/21 00:01:10',
    '08/22/2020',
    '2021-07-18',  // <-- 2nd element (= 3rd row)
    '2021-7-19',
    '2021-07-20',
    '2021-08-21',  // <-- 5th element (= 6th row)
    '2021-8-22',   // <-- 6th element (= 7th row)
    '2021-08-22',  // <-- 7th element (= 8th row)
]

var dates  = dates_str.map(d => new Date(d)); // convert strings to objects (doesn't need in SpreadsheetApp)

var days   = dates.map(d => d.getDate());     // array of days (numbers)
var months = dates.map(d => d.getMonth()+1);  // array of months (numbers)
var years  = dates.map(d => d.getFullYear()); // array of years (numbers)

// function goes through given array from bottom to top 
// and returns the index of last element that is equal whith given element
function get_index(array, element) {
    var ar = array.reverse();
    for (var i in ar) if (ar[i] != element) return ar.length - i;
    return ar.length-1; // return last row index if nothing was found
}

// demo
console.log(get_index(years,  2021));  // output 2 (= 3rd row)
console.log(get_index(months, 8));     // output 5 (= 6th row)
console.log(get_index(days,   22));    // output 6 (= 7th row)
console.log(get_index(days,   23));    // output 7 (= 8th row)
```

I haven't tired but supposedly it should work independently from formatting dates on the sheet, because it takes date objects from the sheet and get their days, month, and years as numbers, it's no matter what formatting they have on spreadsheet as soon as they can be successfully parsed.

Moreover this way you, supposedly, can get "first" row for hours, minutes and seconds if they are in your table.

Comment: I will give this a try now. just a small correction: I need to find the number of the first row that contains the same day as the **second** last row in my table. Don't know if that makes a difference to you. It's just a matter of doing a -1 to the `getLastRow`.

Comment: It works. What if I wanted to get the number of the first row that contains the same **month** as the second last row in my table? And I will need for year as well. Because I am running the day, month and year grouping functions separately.

Comment: This simply implementation works with days only. For month and years it should be different approach. It can be done without TextFinder as well. You need to get the dates as objects, to convert them into ISO format put in array and process them inside the array. It doesn't matter what format the dates has on the sheet. Inside the script they all will be yyyy-mm-dd. About the same algorithm is  in the function `get_rows_array()`. I can try to implement it tomorrow.

Comment: Someone showed me some code but I couldn't get it to work because still haven't got around to understand arrow functions. But might be useful somehow. Can't paste in the comments so I answered my question with this code and link to the other question.

Comment: Also added more code which will work for `YYYY` regardless of date format. Seems like the hardest to get is `MM/YYYY` or when `d` is in between or `YYYY/MM`.

Comment: *because still haven't got around to understand arrow functions* -- actually, me too, to some degree. I'm already can write these functions, but I'm often failing when it's need to read someones ones. :) I've updated my "answer" (not quite an answer, you know)

Comment: Good news: I found a way for filtering `Y`, `M` and `d` without text finder tricks and in any date format and timezone. So I used another trick but it was more fun and I got to learn more about coding etc. So I added the working code as an answer to my question in case you're curious. I use array ntersection. Of course I got loads of help from people here at SO. Cheers and thanks for all your help! Now on to the next phase: Adding a new row above a row block of same `Y` with the `Y` number and in case of month block with the `M` name so its easy to navigate. Will use maybe `insertRowBefore()`.

Comment: Oh I only saw now your updated answer. I don't think SO notifies on updated answers. But I should have seen your comment. Maybe I skipped it. Thanks! Now I need to see if that approach makes more sense.

Comment: `range.getValues()` gives me an array of arrays like: `[ [ Sat Aug 29 2020 00:30:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) ],   [ Sat Aug 29 2020 12:30:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) ],   [ Sun Aug 30 2020 00:30:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) ] ]`. How to declare `var dates_str` to a simple array like in your demo? I tried `getDisplayValues()` although it simplifies date format it is an array of arrays not array. Also it gets a row number for index which is wrong. I guess it's not giving me the row number but array index number which starts from 0 and not 1 like the rows? Maybe I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `getValues()` should get you **objects**. It's no matter how they look in Looger.log() output. If you want to get some particular formatted strings, you have to use something like this var `date_str = Utilities.formatDate(date_obj, timezone, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')` where `timezone` can be `'GMT+00'`, etc. This way you will get **string** `30/12/2021 17:35:15` for example. For `GMT+01` you will get the string `30/12/2021 18:35:15` from the same date object. Etc.

Comment: Ok I think I finally found a solution I think (with help of course). I edited the answer in case you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Some code I got on another question when I asked for the first time how to get the first row of a block of rows with same day. This I couldn't connect it do my Dummy file since I don't really understand how an arrow function would work:

```
const findIndex = (day, month, year, rows) =>
  rows.findIndex(
    row =>
      new Date(row[0]).getDate() === day &&
      new Date(row[0]).getMonth() === month - 1 &&
      new Date(row[0]).getFullYear() === year
  ) + 1;

const yourFunc = () => {
  const rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  const index = findIndex(5, 9, 2021, rows); // first row for 5th of September
  console.log(index);
};
```

From here:
[Getting row number when day changes on column 1 with dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068383/getting-row-number-when-day-changes-on-column-1-with-dates)

////////////////

From a recent question I have yet another suggestion which is working for the Month only:

EDIT1:
Actually after several tests this one bellow will only work regardless of date format for Year only. If I need `MM/YYYY`or `dd/MM/YYYY`or any other combination like `MM/dd/YYYY` it will need a specific line of code on the `.filter()` like so:

For `"M/d/YYYY"`:

```
.filter(x => getDayMonthYear == new Date(x).getMonth() + 1+"/"+ (new Date(x).getDay()+5)+"/" + new Date(x).getFullYear())  // "M/d/YYYY"
```

For `"dd/MM/YYYY"`:

```
.filter(x => getDayMonthYear == new Date(x).getDay()+5 +"/"+("0" + (new Date(x).getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + new Date(x).getFullYear())  //  "dd/MM/YYYY"
```

For `"MM/YYYY"`:

```
.filter(x => getMonthYear == ("0" + (new Date(x[0]).getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + new Date(x[0]).getFullYear())  // MM/YYYY
```

This one works well when I need to group just by Year so it works with any date format `"YYYY"`:

```
.filter(x => getYear == new Date(x[0]).getFullYear())  // YYYY
```

Full code using `.filter()` for `"MM/YYYY"` (works well when locale is `en_GB` for ex.) :

```
function test(){
  var logSheetNameYR = "LOG";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetNameYR);
  var rowBlock = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();
  var getMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, "GMT+1", "MM/yyyy"); //using UK timezone

  var range = sheet.getRange("A5:A");
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var cells = range.getValues().map((x,i) => x.concat(i + startRow))
                               .filter(x => getMonthYear == ("0" + (new Date(x[0]).getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + new Date(x[0]).getFullYear())
                               .map(x => x[1]);
  Logger.log(cells);
}
```

From here:
[Get row block with createTextFinder() from column A with dates with same M and Y when locale is en_US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69135580/get-row-block-with-createtextfinder-from-column-a-with-dates-with-same-m-and-y/69138720?noredirect=1#comment122197639_69138720)