# Get row block with createTextFinder() from column A with dates with same M and Y when locale is en_US

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, format, date-formatting

I have a sheet where column A has dates. I need to get the row number of a block of rows with the same month and year.
If the Locale of the SpreadSheet is `en_US` then the date format is something like:

`"M/d/YYYY"`

So `d` is between `M` and `Y`. As you can see:

```
var getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/YYYY");
```

So in order to define the block of rows I need to find/filter from the column A all rows with date like `M/YYYY`. This is easy do to with locale as for ex. `en_GB` where the date format is `dd/MM/YYYY`. Here I just search for `MM/YYYY` without errors.

But because in `en_US` the `d` is between `M` and `Y` that is `M/d/YYYY`, I always get an error:

`Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRowGroup.`

I tried:

```
Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M,yyyy").split(",");
```

I get same error:

`Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRowGroup.`

So this an example of the code I've got. It works ok if SpreadSheet locale is set to United Kingdom which is `en_GB`:

```
function testTimeFormat() {
var logSheetNameYR = "LOG";
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetNameYR);
var rowBlock = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();
var getMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/YYYY");
var cells = sheet.getRange("A5:A").createTextFinder(getMonthYear).findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
var firstRowOfBlock = cells[0];
console.log(firstRowOfBlock);
}
```

But when locale is en_US it does not work.

How can I do the same when locale is United States `en_US` or any other date format that separates `M` from `Y` with `d` or any other character in between?

Dummy file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up giving up on text finder tricks and went with @ASyntuBU's suggestion and used his code with a change on the `return` part using `AND` that is `&&` to separate `d` from `m` from `y` this way the filter will not enforce a particular order like `dd/MM/YYYY` but will return into an array all the row numbers with cells on column A which meet the conditions regardless of the order, date format etc. At least I think that's what it does. Thanks @ASyntuBU!

```
// Used for getting the arrays with blocks of rows of `d`+ `m`+ `y`
let range = sheet.getRange("A5:A");
let startRow = range.getRow();
let [y, m, d] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "yyyy,MM,dd").split(",");


  let cells = range.getValues().map((x, i) => x.concat(i + startRow)).filter(x => {   // filter "dd"
        let date = new Date(x[0]);
        let day = date.getDate();
        let month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        return (`${d}` === `${day}` && `${m}` === `${month}` && `${y}` === `${year}`)
    }).map(x => x[1]);
```

When I wan't to group by month, the `return` will be:

```
return (`${m}` === `${month}` && `${y}` === `${year}`)
```

And by group by year:

```
return (`${y}` === `${year}`)
```

This returns row numbers into an array, then we get the `0` (first) position with `cells[0]` to find the row number where the group handle will be placed.

Comment: actually, the order wont matter and it will still work.. the one you are comparing are the outputs of the getter methods, not the actual date. as long as both sides has same order, it should be fine. Try and test it using this condition. ````${dd}${mm}${yyyy}` == `${day}${month}${year}````. if dd = day, mm = month and yyyy = year, resulting condition by combining the 3 of them for both sides should still return the same which is true. But yeah, this will still do. upvoted.

Comment: I believe you, thing is when I tried `${dd}${mm}${yyyy} == ${day}${month}${year}` it only worked if the locale was `en_GB`. If I changed the locale to `en_US` it wouldn't work. I guess it's because `${dd}${mm}${yyyy} == ${day}${month}${year}` is order dependent? With the `${d} === ${day} && ${m} === ${month} && ${y} === ${year}` I can set locale to anywhere even Latvia or Hong Kong etc and it will still work. Unless I'm doing something wrong which is entirely possible but I tried your suggestion so many times that I have no clue what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Hmm.. If that's the case and this is working with you then I might be wrong. I can't think of anything that might cause it. If it works then that's already good.

Answer (score 2):

The `createTextFinder` won't be ideal for this because this method will only work on exact text values shown on every cells of range `A5:A` on your sheet.

### Recommendation

You can try this sample script below using string manipulation of the array. This will return the rows of all cells that matches the `getMonthYear` on range `A5:A`:

***Sample Script:***

```
function test(){
  var logSheetNameYR = "LOG";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetNameYR);
  var rowBlock = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();
  var getMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, "GMT+1", "MM/yyyy"); //using UK timezone

  var range = sheet.getRange("A5:A");
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var cells = range.getValues().map((x,i) => x.concat(i + startRow))
                               .filter(x => getMonthYear == ("0" + (new Date(x[0]).getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + new Date(x[0]).getFullYear())
                               .map(x => x[1]);
  Logger.log(cells);
}
```

***Sample Result:***

[image]

***Sheet:***

[image]

Comment: This is good! If I want to adapt this to do the same just for Years like `var getMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, "GMT+1", "yyyy"); ` in other words, if I want to get the first row number of the last block of the same/last year, will it work too or would it need some adaptation? On my main file I need to do the same for days, month and years.

Comment: I tried it and it logs this: `[]`so its null.

Comment: You could just simply edit the `.filter()` method from the code. For example, `.filter(x => getYear == new Date(x[0]).getFullYear())` ---> if you have `var getYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, "GMT+1", "yyyy");`

Comment: If I use `"dd/MM/YYYY"` for days it also returns `null`.   Ok I will try.

Comment: Yes it works! What about for only days? In case I'm search for`dd/MM/YYYY`. In case I have `getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/YYYY");` ?

Comment: Oh you answered faster than I asked. Thanks!

Comment: For `"dd/MM/YYYY"` for days & you have this `var getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");` ---> edit your `.filter()` into this `.filter(x => getDayMonthYear == new Date(x).getDay()+5 +"/"+("0" + (new Date(x).getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + new Date(x).getFullYear())`

Comment: Basically, you just need to make sure that the formatting of your dates after the `==` operator are correct on the `.filter()` method.

Comment: Its returning `[]` and `null` this last part for the day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236989/discussion-between-irvin-jay-g-and-verminous).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify the format, you just need to separately get the details (day, month, year) for easy comparison.

Another thing to note, never sacrifice readability for shorter code. Use variables if necessary.

```
  // get all details of the date
  var mmddyyyy = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy"); //using UK timezone
  // split to each category for easier access
  var [mm, dd, yyyy] = mmddyyyy.split('/');

  var range = sheet.getRange("A5:A");
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var cells = range.getValues().map((x,i) => x.concat(i + startRow))
                               .filter(x => {
                                 var date = new Date(x[0]);
                                 var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                                 var year = date.getFullYear();
                                 var day = date.getDate();
                                 // date properties are always the same on different formats
                                 // because these are outputs of date methods
                                 // just create a combination of the variables
                                 // e.g. you want to match the exact date
                                 return (`${dd}${mm}${yyyy}` == `${day}${month}${year}`)
                                })
                               .map(x => x[1]);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will work for other locales like `en_US` which is `M/d/YYYY`? Because it's only working for `en_GB` for me. Because my problem is not the format like text, numeric or etc, it's the different order of the `M`, `d` and `Y` which will change according to locale defined by user in the Spreadsheet Settings. Many countries use `dd/MM/YYYY` like in `en_GB` but many others use something else. US being the main one because about half the users will be from the US.

Comment: Actually this code worked with a few tweaks for my needs. I had to find a way to search for `d`, `m` and `y` independently of the format and order. Then get the arrays with the blocks of rows and intersect the arrays to get the unique row numbers. Something like: `cells = cellsM.filter(e => ~cellsY.indexOf(e));`

Comment: As i said, format won't matter as getmonth will always get the month, same with other getter methods. It doesnt get a specific position in the date, but the specific details you want, day month or year. Make use of date methods to make your script easier to understand. I recommend you make use of existing methods instead of reinventing the wheel which is one of the rules most programmers follow.

Comment: Yes but maybe you don't understand what I need . I have a column with only dates and it will get big after few years. When a month is over I need a way to group its rows. So I need to get an array with row numers of the month that passed. If I call August for ex. for `M` it will get August for other years too. So to get just the last August I need the search term or filter to include `M` and `Y`. This works with most date formats except with formats that separate `Y` from `M` like `en_US` does with `d` in the middle. I needed a way to use a code that adapts to every date format.

Comment: So what about if I use as `return` this: `return (${d} === ${day} && ${m} === ${month} && ${y} === ${year});`. Won't this grab the dates regardless of the order/format of `y`, `m` and `d`?  (I took away the ``` to avoid the code thing).

Comment: Yes it works perfectly! Thank you! Is it ok if I answer my question with this change? Or would you prefer to change yours and I will accept the answer?

Comment: Feel free to post and accept your answer since you still modified mine. Simply referring me in your answer would be fine.